# Nested Jolt Transformation issue

Tags: json, jolt

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": 1,
      "itemName": "OKRA",
      "stock": [
        {
          "stock": 50,
          "salePrice": 150
        },
        {
          "stock": 100,
          "salePrice": 75
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "itemId": 2,
      "itemName": "CUCUMBER",
      "stock": [
        {
          "stock": 100,
          "salePrice": 10
        },
        {
          "stock": 200,
          "salePrice": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "count": 2,
  "total_records": 428,
  "current_page": 1,
  "per_page": 2,
  "total_pages": 215
}
```

Excepted Output should be

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": 1,
      "itemName": "OKRA",
      "salePrice": 150,
      "stock": 50
    },
    {
      "itemId": 1,
      "itemName": "OKRA",
      "salePrice": 75,
      "stock": 100
    },
    {
      "itemId": 2,
      "itemName": "CUCUMBER",
      "salePrice": 10,
      "stock": 100
    },
    {
      "itemId": 2,
      "itemName": "CUCUMBER",
      "salePrice": 5,
      "stock": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

My spec file

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "stock": {
            "*": {
              "@2": "itemsArray[]",
              "@": "stockArray[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "itemsArray": {
        "*": { // bizArray index
          "itemId": "items[&1].itemId",
          "itemName": "items[&1].itemName",
          "stock": "items[&1].stock[&1].stock",
          "salePrice": "[&1].stock[&1].salePrice"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Anyone help me to get the Excepted output.I am new to JOLT.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "stock": {
            "*": {
              "@2": "itemsArray[]",
              "@": "stockArray[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "itemsArray": {
        "*": {
          "itemId": "items[&1].itemId",
          "itemName": "items[&1].itemName"
        }
      },
      "stockArray": {
        "*": {
          "stock": "items[&1].stock",
          "salePrice": "items[&1].salePrice"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your case as more symbolically as more dynamically using the following transformation logic :

```json
[
  { // form independent arrays of the attributes those will be returned within the desired
    // JSON result
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // the level of "items" array
        "*": { // the indexes of the array
          "stock": {
            "*": {
              "@2": { // replicate the respective values from 2 upper level
                // eg. the same level with the "stock" array
                "*": "[&1].&",
                "&2": "x" // get rid of the caller array and keep the other elements 
                  // by setting their values to an arbitrary literal(in this case "x")                        
                  // unlike to upper line which's preceded by an identifier 
              },
              "*": "[&1].&" // else case
                // like the innermost ones
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // reform new objects by indexes of the outer objects and of those independent arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2_&.&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  },
  { // sort in alphabetical order
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]